# How to find the Gray Level Co-occurrence Matrix (GLCM) of a given matrix?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I need to calculate the Gray Level Co-occurrence Matrix (GLCM) of a given matrix. In `Matlab` there is a built-in function to do [this](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/create-a-gray-level-co-occurrence-matrix.html). However, it only considers the co-occurrence along the horizontal direction.

Is there any such function in Mathematica?

If not, how to find the GLCM which will consider the co-occurrence along any arbitrary direction and with any arbitrary kernel size(to consider the neighbors)?

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation for  [`ImageCooccurrence`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageCooccurrence.html)

For the test image

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
MatrixPlot[
 ImageCooccurrence[
  Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnpBr.png"]
  , 32
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]